# Run multiple Pre-request scripts sequentially in postman

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I have created a postman collection consisting of around 80-100 requests. And I have categorized them in 5 separate folders. Each folder has its own functionality.

I want the multiple pre-request scripts to be run sequentially for the specific request. What is currently happening is the number of scripts I have in one post-script is running but not in sequence. It runs randomly or not sure how. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Pre Request script execute per request (if its in request) or once for all the reqeusts  in the collection if its collection level .  You cannot control the flow of pre-request script alone., but you can control what request osend nex use postman.setNextRequest

https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/building-workflows/

This will run pre-reqeust script of that particular request plus send taht request